# natural language processing for complex sentences

Tags: botframework

I am trying to find an engine that can solve a problem as the below :

" I want one cheese burger with extra cheese and one chicken cheese burger without cheese . "

The problem here that using either LUIS or api.i , the above sentence will return intents as eat for example and entities(food entity) will return cheese burger and chicken cheese burger , but I wont be able to see that there are two intents in the sentence each having it's own entities .

How can I solve this issue with any natural language processing engine ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Botframework `LuisDialog` you can create a class that LUIS sends the query result to as a `LuisResult` param which contains the properties `Intents` and `Entities`, with the associated score for each intent.

Hope that helps